# How Can I Name An Entity With a Player's name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hello I wanted to summon a blaze using command block and I wanted to name him like "**DaniyalShafiq's Blaze**" is this possible.I have tried /summon Blaze ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"@p's Blaze",CustomNameVisible:1b} and I have also tried /summon Blaze ~ ~ ~ {Customname:"",{Selector:@p},"'s Blaze",CustomNameVisible:1b}

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically insert data into NBT (only raw JSON strings allow it somewhat, but that doesn't apply here). So using @p with CustomName is not possible. You can only "hardcode" values.